# JavaScript fluid layout

Tags: javascript, css, html

I've resorted to using a fluid layout with jQuery in my layout but have into a couple difficulties I wanted to ask questions about.

Right now the layout looks like this:

[image]

I'd like it to look like this:

[image]

whilst retaining the fluidity of it. How can I go about achieving this?

I've uploaded the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/methuselah/V44Jw/3/

Comment: may be http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/ultimate-3-column-holy-grail-pixels.htm can help a bit

Answer (score 1):

It's all possible with CSS and no JavaScript at all. You should not use JavaScript to create a fluid layout.

You have done some good work with your CSS. An easy way would be to use absolute positioning for the elements, with relative sizing. Inside each div with `position: relative;` you can do absolute positioning at your will.

A good practice is to leave the size calculation to the browser. If you have a look at this example:

```
#someDiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 80%;
}
```

This div will have 100% height of its parent element, due to the offset `0` from top and bottom. Try to improve your fiddle, it might solves all your problems. Ask again if you struggle.